# How to return values from a for...of loop?

Tags: javascript

How to return values from a `for...of` loop?

```
let years = [2000, 2001, 2002]


for(let [index, value] of years.entries()){
  let age = new Date().getFullYear() - value;
  return `user ${index + 1} age is ${age}`
}
```

Comment: `return` without function doesnot work. It will throw `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement`. And also it will run the loop only once. What is expected output. Do you want to change the elements of array `years`

Comment: Even in a function return without some sort of test will always run the loop one time. Maybe you are looking for [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break).

Comment: You would not use a `return` statement to get values from a loop (unless it is inside a function). You will probably get a more useful answer if you edit your question to explain what you are trying to do with `user ${index + 1} age is ${value}`. Do want to store it for access with a variable, output it to an html element or the console, etc?

Comment: Please describe the expected output/result.

Comment: It would like what you want to do is to process the array, and return that result.  So in your sample, you take in a list of years, and return a list of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to return an array of strings? If so, I would recommend using a [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. It could be written as:

```
const stringArray = years.map( (value, index) => {
  let age = new Date().getFullYear() - value;
  return `user ${index + 1} age is ${age}`;
});
```

Comment: I think they might.  It looks like in an attempt to have them do the for loop they accidentally did a half-loop half-lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

The return statement stops a loop only if it's inside the function. Otherwise, you will get this error.  Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement(…)

You could use a map for this

```
let  years = [2000, 2001, 2002]
years.map( (idx , val) => {
let age = new Date().getFullYear() - val;
  return `user ${idx + 1} age is ${age}`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use return outside function. And it is most of the time a bad practice to use it inside a loop since you seem to begin with javascript.

In this case if you want to extract data from loop process you should declare and fill array like this :

```js
let years = [2000, 2001, 2002];
let array = [];

for(let [index, value] of years.entries()){
   let age = new Date().getFullYear() - value;
   array.push(`user ${index + 1} age is ${age}`);
}

console.log(array);
```